# JS, что-то не так с циклом

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
function phrase_massive() {
    document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= phrases.length; i++) {
         document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrases[i];
    }
}
setTimeout(phrase_massive, 1000);
```

Не работает, пишет "undefined". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так

Comment: `i <= phrases.length` замените на `i < phrases.length` и будет счастье )

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, спасибо, но всё равно не то. В консоли показывает, но не в спане. И вообще я хотела сделать поочередный вывод. Т.е. есть фраза в спане, и она заменяется фразой с массива каждую, припустим, секунду. Возможно, массив неправильно написала? Вид var phrases = [ "bla", "second_bla"...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с [замыканием](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure) :

```js
var phrases = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function phrase_massive() {
  document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
    setTime(i);
  }
};

function setTime(_i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrases[_i].toString();
  }, _i * 1000);
};

phrase_massive();
```

```html
<p id="phrase"></p>
```

Вариант с использованием [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) :

```js
var phrases = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function phrase_massive() {
  document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrases[i].toString();
    }, i * 1000);
  }
};

phrase_massive();
```

```html
<p id="phrase"></p>
```

Comment: Благодарю)  Второй вариант мне больше понятен. Только можно вопрос? Почему в первом варианте используется "_i", а не просто "i"?

Comment: да просто разные названия переменных, чтобы не путаться

Comment: спасибо, тогда вопросов больше нет)